# SuperSearch Results for Entries using Playa displaying Entry ID

Tags: playa, supersearch

When I search through SuperSearch and get a result that uses the Playa field the Entry ID ## of the associated field is incorporated.  For instance, I'm searching projects which are associated with a given staff member via Playa.  My result comes back "Project Title, [entry_id##] Staff Member" where the entry_id## is replaced with the actual entry_id.

Any thoughts?
Playa 4.4.5
SuperSearch 2.1.3
EE 2.6.1

Thanks,
Drew

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand your problem but check this URL and see if it will help you:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/super_search/third_party_support/#pt_playa

Regard's.